# If I include images as resources in my Visual Studio project, do these images get compiled into the executable?

Tags: c++, winapi

What I mean is, if I want to compile and distribute my program, do I have to include folders in the download that have the images and then link a relative path to those folders in my code? Or if I include the images as a resource, is their data saved in the machine code of the program, allowing me to just handout out an executable?

Comment: @JonathonReinhart So this saved him 15 seconds right?

Comment: @ChristianVeenman Sure, not counting his time to type up the question. And, at the expense of others' time.

Comment: I actually did do about 10 minutes of reading about the subject, and I couldn't seem to find what I was looking for. I don't think I was using the correct search terms. So then I went and moved my pictures to a different folder, and they didn't show up. But now I realize that must of been because I rebuilt the project...

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If you're using resources correctly, and it built successfully, it doesn't matter where the original images are, or if they exist at all.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart My apologies for the way I responded. I didn't mean it bad. Just some poeple have a hard time founding out those things themselves and for them and mayby other poeple that don't have Visual Studio yet it might be easier to ask don't you agree?

Answer (score 3):

[Resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_%28Windows%29) are embedded into the EXE / DLL.

- [MSDN: Using Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Windows uses a resource section so technically its not part of the machine code, it just handled elsewhere within the exe.
Resource compilation is by default unconditional ( opposed to some compiler/linker settings when code only gets compiled/linked when it's used ) so if you specify the binary file as a resource the final exe will have it regardless if it's being used or not.

Later you can use the [windows resource functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468901%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) windows resource functions to get the data, altho keep in mind that its just data if it's a resource so you have to explicitly write it to the disk and then you can executed it, not from the resource itself.